# RegEx vb.net MatchCollection is full of Empty Strings

Tags: regex, vb.net

I am very new to using Regular Expressions. (I have read Ben Forta's book and have learned from asking a previous question on here. I am trying to put my learning into practice.)

So, given this string: "[Class 4C] Physics 101 [~2] [#14 Worthington 5] FW"

I'd like these results:

- "[Class 4C]"
- "Physics 101"
- "[~2]"
- "[#14 Worthington 5]"
- "FW"

I'm using this vb.net code:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
---
Dim txt As String = "[Class 4C] Physics 101 [~2][#14 Worthington 5] FW"
Dim mc As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(txt, "((?<=\])|(?=\[))")
Dim m As Match
For Each m In mc
   Debug.Print(m.Value)
Next m
```

The result is a System.Text.RegularExpressions.MatchCollection containing 6 empty strings.

Using [RegEx Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3f%3c%3d%5c%5d%29%7c%28%3f%3d%5c%5b%29%29&i=%5bClass+4C%5d+Physics+101+%5b%7e2%5d%5b%2314+Worthington+5%5d+FW&o=i), I see something I can work with in the 'Split List' but what I'm getting in the MatchCollection is the data in the "Table" view.

Screenshots: [Table View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Okz1P.png) | [Split List View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uE3vw.png)

How do I access the array shown in the Split List please? (Or do I need to use a different pattern?)

Comment: The pattern you use consists of 2 lookaround assertions, which are non consuming. You could try using split `(?!^)((?<=\])|(?=\[))`

Comment: Thanks for helping @Thefourthbird but that doesn't work, either in RegEx Storm or vb.net. I just get one fewer empty string.

Comment: You can split on the basis of space. Isn't it?

Comment: I mean you could use `Regex.Split`, use your pattern `((?<=\])|(?=\[))` and remove the empty entries from the array.

Comment: Ah! Perfect! Thank you. Because you replied as a comment rather than an answer, I can't mark it solved. In case it helps someone else, here is my amended code:

`Dim text As String = "[Class 4C] Physics 101 [~2] [#14 Worthington 5] FW"`
`Dim pattern As String = "((?<=\])|(?=\[))"`
`Dim matches() As String = Regex.Split(text, pattern)`
`For Each match As String In matches`
`     Dim trimmedMatch As String = Trim(match)`
`     If trimmedMatch.Length > 0 Then`
`                ' Do things here`
`     End If`
`Next`

Comment: @TodLewis If they don't come back to add an answer, you should add this as an answer yourself. Mark it as community wiki, since you didn't write the expression or if your'e nervous about claiming authorship, and this way proper attribution is less screwed up.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn Great, thank you for letting me know the etiquette. I've done as you suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to [the fourth bird](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5424988/the-fourth-bird) who (in the comments) helped me reach the solution. In case it helps anyone else, here is the answer and updated code:

A [RegEx.Match](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netcore-3.1) returns a collection that contains all of the matches produced from applying the specified Regular Expression pattern. This will normally return only part(s) of a string. As it is often what's needed, example code will often show this way of using Regular Expressions.

However, my requirement was to return ALL of the string, split into sections as defined by the RegEx. This is done using the [RegEx.Split](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split?view=netcore-3.1) function.

The result is what is referred to in [RegEx Storm](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3D%5C%5B%29%29&i=%5BClass%204C%5D%20Physics%20101%20%5B%7E2%5D%5B%2314%20Worthington%205%5D%20FW&o=i) as the 'Split List'.

Here is the modified vb.net code. It splits the string, filters out empty strings and trims-off any leading and trailing whitespace:

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
---
Dim text As String = "[Class 4C] Physics 101 [~2][#14 Worthington 5] FW"
Dim pattern As String = "((?<=\])|(?=\[))"
Dim matches() As String = Regex.Split(text, pattern)
For Each match As String In matches
    Dim trimmedMatch As String = Trim(match)
    If trimmedMatch.Length > 0 Then
        ' Do things here
        Debug.Print(trimmedMatch)
    End If
Next
```

Thanks again [the fourth bird](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%5D%29%7C%28%3F%3D%5C%5B%29%29&i=%5BClass%204C%5D%20Physics%20101%20%5B%7E2%5D%5B%2314%20Worthington%205%5D%20FW&o=i). Really appreciated.